# Picking a model when everyone in the dependent group has the outcome

Tags: regression, logistic, model

I have a project in which a group of people have all had an adverse effect (dependent group).

I want to find out whether a set of variables such as smoking, exercise etc. (independent variables) have a statistically significant effect on having an adverse effect.

I've thought about running a logistic regression (adverse effect: no/yes) with the independent variables. But the problem is, everyone would be in the "yes" group.

Would that be the correct thing to do? Usually when I've worked with logistic regression, not everyone in the dependent group has had the outcome so I'm not sure if that changes things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everyone has the same value on the dependent variable then you have nothing to model. There's nothing to do here, at least with regard to the dependent variable, except get more data.

Comment: When you just write it out like that it becomes painfully obvious. Thank you. I must have been confused for a minute there.